# difference between mongoose js virtuals and custom setter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Could someone clarify the difference between Mongoose JS's virtuals and custom setters comparatavely?

I searched on google nothing useful came out. To me it seems they serve to the same purpose, so why to keep them both?

Comment: Did you read mongoose documentation? I think it's clear. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html & http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html Or I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

> Mongoose supports virtual attributes. Virtual attributes are
>   attributes that are convenient to have around but that **do not get
>   persisted to MongoDB**.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between virtuals and setters is that virtual allows to have fields that are not stored in the database and the setters actually change some field that is stored in the database. So I would say that is the matter of persistence of data in the database.